# In Substrate, what's the difference between `spec_version` and `authoring_version`?

Tags: substrate, parity-io

Each Substrate runtime has a [RuntimeVersion](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0/sp_version/struct.RuntimeVersion.html). The fields in this RuntimeVersion struct indicate when various aspects of the runtime change and each field has its own semantics described in those docs.

I'm not sure what `authoring_version` means and when exactly it should change. The description in the docs is not totally clear to me

```
authoring_version: u32

authoring_version is the version of the authorship interface.
An authoring node will not attempt to author blocks unless this
is equal to its native runtime.
```

If possible please provide examples of upgrades where:

- both `spec_version` and `authoring_version` would change
- `spec_version` would change, but `authoring_version` would not
- `authoring_version` would change, but `spec_version` would not

Answer (score 5):

I will share an answer provided to me by Substrate core developer [Bastian Köcher](https://www.parity.io/people-of-parity-bastian-koecher):

> There aren't that much changes that result in a bump of the `authoring_version`
>
> If you for example change the `BlockBuilder` runtime api in a non-backwards compatible way, you will need to bump the `authoring_version`
>
> As validators will not be able to build new blocks, without updating the node implementation
>
> And if you just change the runtime api in such a way that you make it incompatible to the previous while don't changing any internals in the runtime that would lead to a different storage root, you would only bump the `authoring_version`. However, I expect that this probably never happens in reality